# how to handle WPF listbox selectionchanged event using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am trying to perform listbox changed event in WPF  using MVVM. Please let me know how to do this selectionchanged event.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do it using

1. Add reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` in your project
2. in XAML add `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Then

```
<ListBox>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding YourCommandParameter}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Hi Ummar,

   Thnak you for your answer but i am getting this error

      The attachable property Triggers was not found in Interactions. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: are you getting this in XAML designer? and your project must be compiling and executing fine. What version of Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: yes i am getting in XAML. I am using VS 2010 on windows 7 64 bit OS

Comment: This is because you are using Blend behaviors in your XAML, which are not very much friendly to VS designer, I would prefer to use Expression Blend for designing your GUI. This post might help you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/25e5082d-71ea-41b8-a6e6-dea07449aaa1

Comment: I have tried the following way :
xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity". For this i am getting The property Command  was not found in type InvokeCommandAction error in XAML design

Comment: why not this way? `"xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16357/discussion-between-skumar-and-ummar)

Comment: Suggested edit: For [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki), the namespace is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors`.

Answer (score 35):

You would bind the `SelectedItem` property of the listbox to your property on the ViewModel:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ...>
    ....
</ListBox>
```

In the property there always will be the selected item from the ListBox. If you really need to do something when the selection changes you can do it in the setter of that property:

```
public YourItem SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if(value == _selectedItem)
            return;

        _selectedItem = value;

        NotifyOfPropertyChange("SelectedItem");

        // selection changed - do something special
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to specify TwoWay binding as the mode.

Comment: @ScottNimrod: This should be the default.

Comment: the prop setter would fire ther event even if the Viewmodel is loaded, woludn't it? as you bind the itemssoruce, the selecteditem will be set too... Normally I expect an action only if user changes the value, not the code.....

Comment: Notice that for `SelectionMode="Multiple"` and `"Extended"` this will work only for the first item selected - when you expand the selection **`SelectedItem` will not change**. The accepted answer works fine in that case (and allows passing ListBox's `SelectedItems` list as command parameter: `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=SelectedItems}"`).

Answer (score 0):

you can binding ListBox SelectionChanged Event to command in your ViewModel.

see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18960028/5627499