# WPF Listbox selectionchanged MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a list box in my WPF application. I know how to use the selectionchanged event. However I am trying to follow the MVVM design. However I am not sure how to do this.

I have done this for a button however not sure if I can do the same thing?

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Name="buttImport" 
    Content="Import File" 
    Command="{Binding CommandButtImport}" 
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
```

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{       
    // for the button that imports the orders file
    public ICommand CommandButtImport { get; set; }

    public ViewModel() 
    {
        CommandButtImport = new MyCommands(
            ExecuteCommandButtImport,
            CanExecuteCommandButtImport);
    }

    private bool CanExecuteCommandButtImport(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // import button
    private void ExecuteCommandButtImport(object parameter)
    {
      // some code
    }
}
```

**EDIT Please ignore code above**

I have changed my code so have reposted below what I currently have. I have a strange issue. The XAML - Main Code contains the code for my datagrid. The block below App - XAML contains the styling for most of my app, but is just a snipet.

Also

Code Line added beneath my datagrid in XAML - Main Code for testing purposes.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.DuplicateSecurities, ElementName=dataGridOrders}" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.Security, ElementName=dataGridOrders}"/>
```

My datagrid loads fine. When I click on a row, the row expands to show a list of Securities. The issue I have is that in this listbox when I click on an item nothing happens. However the Listbox which I added beneath my datagrid for testing purposes does work. For example I click on one of the items and my row is updated, also the listbox in my row detail becomes selected. Its very strange why the listbox in my rowdetail doesn't work but the one beneath my datagrid does. Any ideas?

XAML - Main Code

```
<StackPanel>
        <!-- The data grid to display orders-->
        <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}" 
                  x:Name="dataGridOrders" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                  Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate}"
                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}"                      
                  RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader}"
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}"                      
                  RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DG_RowDetail}"                      
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Silver"
                  RowHeaderWidth="30"                      
                  Margin="25,5,20,15">                                                     

            <DataGrid.Columns>                    
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Action">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.StatusList}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding StatusGood}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.StatusList}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding StatusGood}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>                    
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fund" Binding="{Binding Account}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Security ID" Binding="{Binding Security.ID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ThinkFolio Security ID" Binding="{Binding ThinkFolioSecurityID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Security Name" Binding="{Binding Security.Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Buy/Sell" Binding="{Binding TransType}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding OrderQunatity, StringFormat=\{0:N0\}}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Currency" Binding="{Binding BuyCurrency}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manager" Binding="{Binding FundManager}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Reason" Binding="{Binding OrderReason}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reject Reason" Binding="{Binding RejectReason}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>                    
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.DuplicateSecurities, ElementName=dataGridOrders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.Security, ElementName=dataGridOrders}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

App XAML

```
  <!-- Row Detail Template for Data Grid -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DG_RowDetail">
        <Grid x:Name="RowDetailGrid"                  
              Margin="5"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="500"
                    Height="80"
                    CornerRadius="5">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                               Margin="5,0,0,5"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Text="Select Security Identifier">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="lbIdentifier" ItemsSource="{Binding DuplicateSecurities}" SelectedItem="{Binding Security}"                                 
                             SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="0,2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ID}" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </Border>                                        
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{       
    public ICommand CommandButtImport { get; set; }                     // for the button that imports the orders file
    public ICommand CommandButtSend { get; set; }                       // the button where the user sends the orders in our data grid to thinkFolio
    public ICommand CommandButtExit { get; set; }                       // exit application

    private QoEMain _QoEManager;                                        // manages the Model
    public QoEMain QoEManager { get { return this._QoEManager; } set { _QoEManager = value; } }

    private OrderBlocks _orderBlock;                                    // order block - contains all the order information
    public OrderBlocks OrderBlock
    {
        get
        {
            return this._orderBlock;
        }
        set
        {
            this._orderBlock = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OrderBlock");
        }
    }
 }
```

OrderBlocks Class which contains the other classes

```
 public class OrderBlocks : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private List<Order> _orders;
    [XmlElement("tF_Transactions")]
    public List<Order> Orders { get { return _orders; } set { _orders = value; OnPropertyChanged("Orders"); } }
}
```

Orders Class

```
    public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Security security;
        public Security Security
        {
            get { return security; }
            set { security = value; OnPropertyChanged("Security"); }
        }

        List<Security> duplicateSecurities;
        public List<Security> DuplicateSecurities
        {
            get { return duplicateSecurities; }
            set { duplicateSecurities = value; OnPropertyChanged("DuplicateSecurities"); }
        }
```

Security Class

```
 public class Security : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private string _id;
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public Security() { }

    public Security(string newID, string newName)
    {
        ID = newID;
        Name = newName;
    }
```

**Edit - My code now works please see the code snippet below that works for me**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.DuplicateSecurities, ElementName=dataGridOrders}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.Security, ElementName=dataGridOrders}">
```

Comment: And the question is ....

Comment: Can you post what you've tried and the results of those attempts?

Comment: Well the example I've posted above works for a button but I would like to know how to do this for a listbox when the selection changes.

Comment: well with MVVM, have your `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` property of the `ListBox` bound to the VM and in the setter for the property do what you need to do as it would trigger when the selection in the `ListBox` changes accordingly. Is this what you're question is about?

Comment: I do not have any results as I am unsure of what to do. I have just been searching the internet without any joy

Comment: In my VM I have added the following code below, `private string _selectedID { get; set; } public string SelectedID { get { return _selectedID; } set { if (value == _selectedID) return; else _selectedID = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedID"); } }`

Comment: my listbox looks like below, `<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="lbIdentifier" ItemsSource="{Binding DuplicateHolder}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedID}"` I should point out my listbox has a datatemplate than contains a grid which contains two textboxes.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Example of binding ListBox `SelectionChanged` Event to command in your ViewModel

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
   <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
      <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </ie:EventTrigger>
  </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox >
```

In your `ViewModel` :

```
public class myViewModel
{

    public myViewModel()
    {
        SelectedItemChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>((selectedItem) => 
        {
             // Logic goes here
        });
    }

    public List<SomeData> SomeCollection { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<object> SelectedItemChangedCommand { get; set; }
}
```

This particular example uses Prism MVVM Framework, but you can apply the same idea with any other MVVM framework you are using as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: If anybody gets errors while using solution provided in this answer then please refer my answer below : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26949499/2284240

Comment: you want the following namespace at the top to use that "ie:" `xmlns:ie="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

Comment: Thanks, this helped getting me on the way. Just to mention. You need to add System.Windows.Interactivity to the references of your project. And for those using the RelayCommand commonly found, just hook it up like a regular command and you get the selected object in the parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good solution ...
I add that if you use "caliburn.micro" you should "RelayCommand" instead of "DelegateCommand" and it will work fin.

Comment: This solution is nonsense.  Handling an event does not violate MVVM. MVVm does not mean to use a `ICommand` for everything (by force). This is an old post, but I hope you know it better by now. You can always bind to the `SelectedItem` òr `SelectedIndex` to trigger an action in your view model.

Comment: It doesn't works if list has only one item.

Answer (score 25):

using `SelectionChanged` with MVVM is quite simple:

An approach could be to bind to the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ListBox` and in the property setter in the VM, act accordingly as it would be triggered whenever the property changes.

Example: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/anyawxz42133b1c/MvvmLight38.rar)

In this example whenever the selected index changes, the value of that item is increased by one.

the main bit is:

```
public int SelectedIndex {
  get {
    return _selectedIndex;
  }

  set {
    if (_selectedIndex == value) {
      return;
    }

    // At this point _selectedIndex is the old selected item's index

    _selectedIndex = value;

    // At this point _selectedIndex is the new selected item's index

    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedIndex);
  }
}
```

xaml would just be:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" />
```

`Items` is the collection of items we bind to.

Comment: Binding the `SelectedIndex` seems like a bad idea to me ... How would you get the actual item that the selection represents? plus this will mean that you'll have to implement all the code that depends on the new selected item in the setter (not talking about devision to sub methods). Another thing is, that this will allow changing the selection straight from the `ViewModel` and not only the UI, which is something you don't want, if your application doesn't have such a use-case

Comment: @Omribitan `Items[SelectedIndex]`

Comment: My point is, you wouldn't want to keep an instance of the selection item the entire lifetime of the `viewModel`, when you only need it when the actual selection changes.

Comment: @Omribitan Sorry gonna have to disagree with you here. If you do not want to do it in the setter, dispatch it back to the same thread or  install an INPC watcher and action there accordingly. `that this will allow changing the selection straight from the ViewModel and not only the UI, which is something you don't want,` err what? It's the VM changing the `SelectedIndex` from the VM is perfectly valid design. You can have cases where you might want to set the index to -1 to remove selections and hundreds of other use cases.

Comment: you can actually do both. Send the `SelectedItem` as a command parameter to execute your logic from there, and keep the `SelectedIndex` binded to your `ViewModel` to `set the index to -1 to remove selections and hundreds of other use cases` :)
You might be right, I've just never encountered binding the `SelectedIndex` so it might just be weird to me ...

Comment: @Omribitan VM's normally have a 1<->1 relation with a View. Just let the VM do what it's meant to do "manage the corresponding view". This is WPF. You could come up with 10's of ways to address this issue. Only thing I disagree'd with is the part of "Binding SelectedIndex to a VM is wrong". Choose whatever approach you're comfortable with :P

Comment: My setter is not getting called when I change the selection in my ListBox. The itemsource is a list called DuplicateHolder which is part of my object OrderBlock. The SelectedItem is bound to a int property in my VM. Does it matter that I have bounded my SelectedItem to an object that is seperate from my ItemSource? I feel as I write this that this could lead to other issues.

Comment: @MarkSawyer this property is for `SelectedIndex` and not `SelectedItem`. They should not interfere with each other. I'd suggest getting the example I linked and trying it out and checking the code to then replicate it for your requirement.

Comment: @Viv my mistake. I'm on a work computer afraid I cannot open rar files. Is there anywhere else I can this example? Thanks

Comment: @MarkSawyer depends on what you can get. can you get zip files? It's just a quick example I put together. So i can upload it as a different format if you want or as a .doc and you can rename it once you download it.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side a doc would be best please. My work are overly safe!

Comment: @MarkSawyer [There ya go](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vy8li3qvvi3sjk/MvvmLight38.doc). You need to rename the extension to **zip** and then extract to get the sln.

Comment: Thanks for that. The setter of the property SelectedIndex does still not get called when I selected a item in my listbox. The itemsSource is bound to DuplicateHolder. Does it matter that the selectedItem is bound to SelectedIndex which DuplicateHolder knows nothing about?

Comment: @MarkSawyer I'm kind of lost with what you actually have in your code when you say `selectedItem is bound to SelectedIndex which DuplicateHolder knows nothing about`. Can you **edit** your question, remove what you have relating to a Button and just post the code you have in xaml for your ListBox, then show the VM code you got for the three properties(`DuplicateHolder`, `SelectedItem`, `SelectedIndex`). This should show what you exactly have.

Comment: @Viv, The value might be -1 at first selection. I therefore added ` if (value < 0) { return; }` at the beginning of the set section of your `SelectedIndex` property. Everything else worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

[System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF) package has been deprecated.

Install [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) package

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
     <Behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
          <Behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
               <Behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemChangedCommand}" />
          </Behaviors:EventTrigger>
     </Behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Name your listbox and add `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"` to the InvokeCommandAction line to get a reference to selected item as well.