# How to perform command in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am using MVVM prism and my code is as follows

```
     <ListBox x:Name="myListBox"  Grid.Row="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_mySOurce}" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged">
    </ListBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSelect" 
     Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" Content="Select" Margin="396,0,10,0"></Button>
```

and in my code i have

```
 public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        this.SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.OnSaveClick, this.CanSaveExecute);       
    }

    private void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OnSaveClick(object arg)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Performed Click");
    }
    private bool CanSaveExecute(object arg)
    {
        if (myListBox.SelectedIndex > 0)
            return true;

        else return false;
    }
```

I am not able to fire it at selection changed event.

What am I missing ?

Comment: in myListBox_SelectionChanged fire it SaveCommand.Execute(parameter) ?

Comment: If you want to fire that command at SelectionChanged, then where is the handler of that event?

Comment: [Here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959304/wpf-listbox-selectionchanged-mvvm)

Answer (score 1):

If you're handling a UI event in your view model, then you're *not* using MVVM at all! Handling UI events in the view model completely breaks the separation of concerns that MVVM provides.

However, the short answer is this:

```
private void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SaveCommand.CanExecute(null)) SaveCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

A far better solution is to add another property to data bind to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox"  Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_mySOurce}" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Then the setter for that `CurrentItem` property will be called whenever the `SelectionChanged` event would be called:

```
public YourDataType CurrentItem
{
    get { return currentItem; }
    set
    {
        currentItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        if (SaveCommand.CanExecute(null)) SaveCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not convinced yet of what is worse: have side effects in a property setter (like this last example), or NOT doing it, because it is a very, very convenient and quite elegant way to implement this kind of behavior in WPF/MVVM, a sort of "reactive" thing (as long as you don't forget the hidden side-effect). An interesting discussion here:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/82377/should-properties-have-side-effects

Comment: Perhaps you misread your linked post... there are absolutely no mentions of 'side effects' in setters. Can you think of any downside to this code, because I'd love to hear about it if you do?

Comment: A quite debatable problem is: when anyone sets a property you usually won't expect _other_, indirect things happening behind your back. This behavior is great when it is designed so, and you remember this. But if some colleague has to work with it, the behaviour is not obvious, it's something to be figured out. It has already happened to myself, when house-cleaning classes, to forget to go into the setter and change there too, and then things suddenly stop working. But I would not worry too much about it because, as I said, I think this patterns solves much more problems that it creates.