# WPF Set focus on text box when item added to Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, setfocus

I have a listbox with an Add button mapped to a command backed by a SelectedItem property in the VM.

When an item is added to the listbox i have the SelectedItem set to the new item so it has focus in the listbox. I'd like to have a textbox (data entry for that new item) to have focus.

I've been looking at event triggers but i havent seen a way to cross items but basically I think what i want is an event trigger for the listbox selection change to to set the focus on a text box.

how would i go about doing this?

As an example I have the following XAML code. This will add a Person (name and age property only)

Basically I want the txtName textbox to have focus when an item is selected in the listbox.

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewPerson}"></TextBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding AddPersonDelegateCommand}">Add</Button>
    <Button>Remove</Button>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">

    </ListBox>
    <TextBox Name="txtName" Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"</TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="txtAge" Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Age, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Post the XAML code you have tried

Comment: Thats the thing, I havent found anything that makes sense. I'll post some XAML i'd like it to work on, but i havent had any luck figuring out how i'd write the trigger. Post will be updated in a couple of min

Comment: you can use Interaction Trigger to acheive this. try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297502/how-to-handle-wpf-listbox-selectionchanged-event-using-mvvm

Comment: SelectionChanged event will not be triggered upon adding an item, you need to manually click on the newly added item to trigger it. perhaps an attached behavior can solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the xaml based trigger to set focus on the `txtName` TextBox when `SelectedItem` property is toggled from null

so idea here is that you set `SelectedPerson` property to null followed by the instance of newly created person object, that should do the trick and will set the focus to the desired TextBox

the limitation of this trigger is that you need to set `SelectedPerson` property null before you set to the new object, an attached behavior can solve that issue too, if this is not workable for you.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewPerson}"></TextBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding AddPersonDelegateCommand}">Add</Button>
    <Button>Remove</Button>
    <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             x:Name="list"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox Name="txtName"
             Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Name, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=list}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement"
                                Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="txtAge"
             Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Age, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```