# Make an event bubble up from the children upwards

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events

AFAIK bubbling means that if an event is triggered on the children, the same event will be triggered on the parents.

I have this piece of code:

```
<ListView Name="lvFiles" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabFilePath, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Files,ElementName=trvFiles, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenFileFromTreeView,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    >
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The problem is that if I click on the button, the property `SelectedTabFilePath` from `SelectedItem` will not be filled with data (because I didn't click on the item of the `ListView`).

So, my question is:
Is there any way to trigger the `Click` event of the button and that of the `ListView` too?

Or if not, what would be the way to set the `SelectedTabFilePath` from the `SelectedItem` attribute when I click on that button, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event [is indeed bubbling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#routed-event-information), which means it will be routed up the elements of visual tree until the root element is reached. However, the `Button` itself [**handles the event**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#the-concept-of-handled), because its `Command` property was bound. That means its parent elements, including `ListViewItem` (the item container) will ignore the event, therfore not select the item.

There is a workaround using the fact that the `Button` receives keyboard focus upon clicking. You add an item container style with a trigger that sets the `IsSelected` property of the `ListViewItem` once the keyboard focus is within, denoted by the [`IsKeyboardFocusWithin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property.

```
<ListView ...>
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <!-- ...your other markup. -->
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

[how to handle WPF listbox selectionchanged event using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297502/how-to-handle-wpf-listbox-selectionchanged-event-using-mvvm)

I think you could use interaction to trigger the same command(OpenFileFromTreeView) when the listbox selection changes.

Comment: Interactivity doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
AncestorType={x:Type ListView}
```

What if you try:

```
AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}
```

Comment: Where? I have two places where I have that ancestortype setting